# Shorten the Controller Logic Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller, logic

I'm trying using Laravel login authentication using different guards but I found that there is some repetition within the store method in the Login Controller (the only difference is the guard used, all other logic are the same). I just can't find a way to shorten them into some other logic such as method(function) which can be reusable. So if there is possible way, Please help me out.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);


    if (Auth::guard('instructor')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {

        if (auth('instructor')->user()->status === Instructor::HAS_DEACTIVATED) {
            $request->session()->flush();
            Auth::guard('instructor')->logout();
            return redirect('login')->with(
                'error',
                'Your Account has being deactivated . Please Contact your Administrator!');
        }

        return redirect(route('instructor.dashboard'));


    }
    if (Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {

        if (auth('student')->user()->status === Student::HAS_DEACTIVATED) {
            $request->session()->flush();
            Auth::guard('student')->logout();
            return redirect('login')->with(
                'error',
                'Your Account has being deactivated . Please Contact your Administrator!');
        }
        return redirect(route('student.dashboard'));
    }
    return back()->with('error', 'Credentials provided do not match any record.');
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate function and then call that function.

```
    public static function deleteSession($gaurd)
    {
                $request->session()->flush();
                Auth::guard($gaurd)->logout();
                return redirect('login')->with(
                    'error',
                    'Your Account has being deactivated . Please Contact your Administrator!');

    }
```

Then in your store function call `deleteSession` statically.

```
     if (auth('instructor')->user()->status === Instructor::HAS_DEACTIVATED)
     {
        self::deleteSession('instructor'); //change gaurd according to your need
     }
```

Comment: Using this approach seems to work with some addition requirements to fill in. To pass $request as a parameter in the `deleteSession` function and use the `return` when the calling `self::deleteSession('instructor')` else the error will not be available to the login page. Thanks anyway. I will improve more from your concept.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to go about this, I'm sure there is a better solution, and [@Aqib Javaed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15737223/aqib-javed)'s seems to be it, but here's one way to shorten the code a bit that I could manage. It's not perfect but does the job done.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('instructor')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        $userType = 'instructor';
    } elseif (Auth::guard('student')->attempt(['email' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        $userType = 'student';
    } else {
        return back()->with('error', 'Credentials provided do not match any record.');
    }

    $modelName = ucwords($userType); //turn the user type to its corresponding model name
    if (auth('$userType')->user()->status === $modelName::HAS_DEACTIVATED) {
        $request->session()->flush();
        Auth::guard('$userType')->logout();

        return redirect('login')->with(
            'error',
            'Your Account has being deactivated . Please Contact your Administrator!');
    }

    return redirect(route("$userType.dashboard"));
}
```

Comment: Using this approach bring error such as Class 'Instructor' not found because it is looking for Instructor class and not Instructor as Model within the Model namespace.Error comes with that variable $modelName. So I'm trying finding some other ways

Comment: A model is a class. Your problem is that you haven't imported the model on top. Just add those two lines above your controller class' definition:

use App\Models\Instructor;
use App\Models\Student;